# boost log - handling power off scenario

Tags: c++, boost

I have implemented a global logger using boost 1.63. Here is initialization:

```
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(my_logger, src::severity_logger_mt< severity_level >)
{
    typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_file_backend > file_sink;
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink(new file_sink(
    keywords::file_name = "/var/log/testApp/%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_testApp.log",
    keywords::rotation_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024,
    keywords::auto_flush = true));

    sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(
    keywords::target = "/var/log/testApp/oldLogs",
    keywords::max_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 2,
    keywords::min_free_space = 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 2,
    keywords::max_files = 2));

    sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();

    sink->set_formatter(
    expr::format("[%1%]<%2%> : %3%") %
    expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp") %
    expr::attr< severity_level >("Severity") %
    expr::smessage);

    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
    logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", attrs::local_clock());

    src::severity_logger_mt< severity_level > slg;
    return slg;
}
```

When a program is unexpectedly finished (for example sudo kill -9 pid or power off) a log file is not moved to oldLogs directory (also when a program is run again) and /var/log/testApp directory may contain many log files.

Is it possible to handle such scenario ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to handle such scenario ?

Only with offline means. For example, you could auto-run a script on the next boot time to move the half-written log files to the target directory. Or you could do this the next time your application starts. Boost.Log can help you in this case if you open the log files in append mode (i.e. by passing `keywords::open_mode = std::ios::app` named parameter to the sink constructor) and then immediately call `rotate_file` on the sink backend. This way non-empty log files will get rotated on your application startup, although you won't be able to actually append to the log files.

**Update:**

I've noticed that you're using a timestamp in your log file name. In this case the approach with rotating the log file with Boost.Log won't work because the library will likely open a differently named file next time your application starts. If timestamps are essential, the only alternative left is a script.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Andrey Semashev said, you need to do also the following things:

- drop the *timestamp* from your log file (e.g. `keywords::file_name = "app.log"`) so that the same file is opened when you use `keywords::open_mode = std::ios::app`, and instead put a *timestamp* only for the rotated files (e.g. `keywords::target_file_name = "app_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.log"`)
- before calling `rotate_file()` you need to log something if your app just started, else nothing will happen because the log file is not yet opened.
- you should set `keywords::enable_final_rotation = false` so if instead of a `power off` you have proper shutdown of your machine and app, you don't rotate then as you will do it anyway on the next startup - the fact that `rotate_file()` will rotate `non-empty` logs is irrelevant given that you first need to log something for the log file to be opened so that `rotate_file()` works in the first place, it's a scenario that will never happen.

For more details, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637326/boost-log-text-file-backend-rotate-file-on-demand/66641570#66641570) question.