# Boost log 'text_file_backend' - rotate file on demand

Tags: c++, logging, boost, rotation, boost-log

I want to cover the cases when my process crashes or just does not shutdown properly and the logs are not rotated.

2 specific cases:

- if I use a fixed name for my log file (e.g. `keywords::file_name = "app.log"`) and the process did not manged to rotate the log on shutdown (let's say it crashed), then when it gets restarted, it will override my `app.log` from the instance that crashed. This is bad as that log is particularly interesting.
- if I use a custom name for my log file (e.g. `keywords::file_name = "app_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.log"`) and the process did not manage to rotate the log on shutdown, then when it gets restarted it will create a new `app_YMD_HMS_5N.log` while leaving the previous log file in the same folder (`~/logs`) instead of moving it to history (`bl::keywords::target = "~/logs/history"`). This is also bad because the `logs` folder gets messy and because **only** the rotation folder e.i. target (`logs/history`) is monitored for `max_size` constraints, so the `logs` folder could grow uncontrollably.

After looking into it I came to the conclusion that I would do the following:

- have a fixed name for the log file (e.g. `keywords::file_name = "app.log"`)
- have a custom name with date and index for the rotated log files to be able to have multiple of them (e.g. `keywords::target_file_name = "app_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.log"`.
- open the log file for append (`keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app`).
- immediately after opening the log file, call `rotate_file()` on the `text_file_backend` in order to rotate a `non empty` `app.log` (if the previous app instance didn't manage to properly shutdown the logger).

The problem is that `rotate_file()` has no effect. The log file is not rotated when I call it.
Am I doing something wrong?

Here is how I setup the file sync:

```cpp
// File log
auto file_sink = bl::add_file_log(bl::keywords::target          = "history",
                                  bl::keywords::file_name       = "app.log"),
                                  bl::keywords::target_file_name= "app_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.log"),
                                  bl::keywords::rotation_size   = 25 * 1024 * 1024,
                                  bl::keywords::max_size        = 250 * 1024 * 1024,
                                  bl::keywords::auto_flush      = true,
                                  bl::keywords::open_mode       = std::ios_base::app,
                                  bl::keywords::max_files       = 10);

file_sink->set_formatter(log_fmt);
file_sink->set_filter(bl::trivial::severity >= level);

// In case the previous log was not rotated on shutdown (it's not empty), rotate it now
file_sink->locked_backend()->rotate_file(); // NOT DOING ANYTHING!
```

For consistency, I was thinking to also disable rotation on shutdown (`keywords::enable_final_rotation = false`) in order to only rotate log file on startup, regardless of how my app terminated (crash, kill -9, proper shutdown...) but to get to this I first need to be able to rotate logs on startup.

Comment: File rotation is not happening because the log file is not opened until the first log record is passed to the backend. This is so because the file name may depend on the time when that log record is passed (e.g. when the file name contains a timestamp).

Comment: You are correct. Knowing this, I can update my solution and make it a bit simpler, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrey Semashev mentioned, in order for `rotate_file()` to work, you first need to log something so the log file is actually opened.

Taking this into account I do the following during logger init (on app startup):

- disable rotation on shutdown (`keywords::enable_final_rotation = false`) - this is so for the cases where we don't have a crash, we don't do an extra empty file rotation (in all cases rotation is done on startup or on hitting the `collector limits`).
- open the file for append (`bl::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app`)
- log something like "Rotating logger on demand"
- call `rotate_file()` - this will do the rotation now that log file is opened.

Here is how it looks:

```cpp
 // File log
auto file_sink
    = bl::add_file_log(bl::keywords::target                = "history",
                       bl::keywords::file_name             = "app.log",
                       bl::keywords::target_file_name      = "app_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.log",
                       bl::keywords::rotation_size         = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                       bl::keywords::open_mode             = std::ios_base::app, // Open for append and immediately rotate
                       bl::keywords::enable_final_rotation = false // Rotate only on startup to cover also the crash / kill cases
    );

// Log something so the logger opens the file
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Rotating logs on startup";

// Do the rotation on demand
file_sink->locked_backend()->rotate_file();
```

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something? How do you use BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) from your BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT? I'm guessing that this isn't actually called directly from that, but instead after that runs?

Comment: @aggieNick02 I do not use `BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT`, I have a logger_init() function that does what you see above + add common attributes + the formatting part at the begining of my program.

Comment: Cool, thanks for answering. That makes sense. I'm on windows where the logrotate utility isn't an option, so quite grateful there is a recipe like this to get boost logging to do reliable rotation without assuming clean shutdown.

Comment: A minor tidbit to add. If your frontend is asynchronous (which I recently experimented changing mine too so that logging didn't lead to hiccups in some tight loops), then then you hit the `rotate_file()`, it is likely to do nothing because the backend usually will not have consumed the log statement. An easy workaround is something like `while (!file_sink->locked_backend()->get_current_file_name().empty()) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));}`

Comment: Why not just explicitly add a log before `rotate_file` as part of the `logger initialization` as above? This will guarantee that you would have "consumed" at least one log statement when you get to do rotate. And this initialization procedure should anyway be complete before your start accepting frontend connections. The logged should be one of the first things you setup on startup.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry. What do you mean by "add a log before `rotate_file`"? I do have something like above, but the problem is that when your sink's frontend is async, the log record created before the call to `rotate_file` is passed to the sink frontend's dedicated thread for processing the log statements through the backend. So there is no guarantee (and in fact, it is pretty unlikely) that anything is written to the backend by the time you hit `rotate_file`

Comment: Better than the while/sleep, is just a call to `logging::core::get()->flush();` right after the log statement. That will block until the log record has been processed by all sinks, and `rotate_file()` will then work as before.